# Xamarin : Get SelectedView in a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin

I have a ListView using an adapter SearchEmployeesListAdapter to get populated with a list of employees displayed using a custom Layout.

In the ItemClick event of the ListView I am using the following code to get the View representing the layout of the currently clicked employe

```
    void lstEmployees_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        View view = lstEmployees.SelectedView;

    }
```

But SelectedView property is always returning null value.

What I really need to do is change a property of another child view within this view that has just been clicked.

Any idea what is making it to return null?

Comment: Just a hunch, but the SelectView property could be getting set after the ItemClick event has completed processing..

Comment: Did you try, View view = (sender as ListView).SelectedView ?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same result.